# Call to managedDevices return an error in POSTMAN but works in PowerShell

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I do a `GET` with a valid token to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices
```

and I get this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": {
      "ErrorCode": "Forbidden",
      "Message": {
        "_version ": 3,
        "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID:  c0edc6b3-3d79-431f-b224-b034524e565c - Url: https://fef.msua02.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices?api-version=5018-07-19",
        "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "",
        "RetryAfter": null,
        "ErrorSourceService": "",
        "HttpHeaders": {
          "WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer realm=urn:intune:service,f0f3c450-59bf-4f0d-b1b2-0ef84ddfe3c7"
        }
      },
      "Target": null,
      "Details": null,
      "InnerError": null,
      "InstanceAnnotations": []
    },
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c0edc6b3-3d79-431f-b224-b034524e565c",
      "date": "2018-09-21T15:27:35"
    }
  }
}
```

If I do the same thing using PowerShell with sample code from [Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/ManagedDevices), I successfully get the list of devices.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: There has to be a difference between the calls.  Postman does some funny stuff sometimes.  Show us what you are doing in Postman and what you are doing in Powershell and we might be able to help you find it.

Comment: Also, please add the actual token to your question. That will help determine why you're getting a `Forbidden` back.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The token we were getting was working for application permission access like getting devices and users in AAD but not delegated permissions like managedDevices. I talked to our AAD team and  they are supposed to give us a way to generate the correct token.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and found I had to add the following 3 permissions in Azure to get it working;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/DeviceManagementManagedDevices.Read.All - Delegated
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read - Delegated
https://graph.microsoft.com/DeviceManagementManagedDevices.Read.All - Application
```